# How to mount a VirtualBox .vdi disk on Linux?

Tags: linux, virtualization, virtualbox, mount

I am running Fedora on a VirtualBox. Sometimes to allow for performing some real hardware testing, I need to run my development environment on a physical machine. So I need the hard disk of the virtual machine (the .vdi file) to be interchangeably working on both the virtual machine itself and my physical PC by booting a bootable image, mounting the vdi file, and then chrooting to it.

I thought this was easy to achieve but it seems not. I hope to find an answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mount it as a loopback device.  Tools you can use are just 'mount' or 'losetup'.  The trick is knowing the required offset.  For that you need 'vditool' or 'vdiinfo'.

Here is a nice article that explains it well:

http://muralipiyer.blogspot.com/2008/02/mounting-virtualbox-vdi-disk-authentic.html

Comment: Is this for fixed drives only, or will it work for expanding type VDI's (has anyone tried?)

Comment: This is for fixed disks only. This method will not work with dynamic disks.

Comment: If neither `vditool` nor `vdiinfo` is available, find the offset manually by opening hex editor and searching for `55AA` pattern which should be located at `0x*****1FE` — that is last 2 bytes in 16-column view, preceded by `0000` at `0x*****1FE`. If that disk contains MBR code, you will also see “GRUB”, “LILO” or other relevant substrings before that, mixed with machine code. In case of GPT it will contain zeroes though, but “EFI PART” right after, at `0x*****200`. Other partitioning schemes have their own recognizable signatures as well.

Comment: `vditool` has been made obselete by `vbox-img` i believe, see https://www.virtualbox.org/changeset/57531/vbox

Answer (score 1):

OpenSuse here, vdfuse works just fine for me both fixed and dynamic images. 
Download the rpm from :
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Virtualization/openSUSE_Factory/x86_64/vdfuse-8.2a-5.54.x86_64.rpm

1. install (ignore file checksum by pressing i when prompted)
2. create a dir for first mount point
3. run `sudo vdfuse -f "/home/sys1.vdi" /VBMount`
4. create a dir for second mount point
5. run `sudo mount /VBMount/Partition1 /VBMountPart1/`

Answer (score 1):

Since the accepted answer seems to have been made obsolete (`vditool` has been made obselete by `vbox-img` i believe, see [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/changeset/57531/vbox)), here is what I did on my linux system to mount a .vdi image:

1. run `vbox-img info --filename /path/to/image.vdi`. Save the uuid listed next to the line beginning with `Header: uuidCreation`
2. run `vboximg-mount -i [UUID] /path/to/intermediate/mountpoint` with the UUID from the last step to mount the image (mine was a /vdi containing a windows install) ([source](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/05/mount-virtualbox-vdi-ubuntu/))
3. (Optional) to get an idea of what is on each partition/which one you may want to mount, run `sudo fdisk -lu /path/to/intermediate/mountpoint/vhdd`
4. Check for the next available loop mountpoint using `losetup -f`, it will likely be /dev/loop0 if you havent done this before, but doesn't hurt to double check - these instructions will assume you are using loop0 ([source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/316407))
5. run `sudo losetup -P /dev/loop0 /path/to/intermediate/mountpoint/vhdd` ([source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/316407)). this will generate several mountpoints with a partition-based naming scheme (`/dev/loop0p1`, `/dev/loop0p2` .etc)
6. mount the individual partition you are interested in with `sudo mount /dev/loop0p[N] /path/to/mountpoint`, replacing `[N]` with the partition number you want.

To unmount:

1. `sudo umount /path/to/mountpoint` to unmount your files
2. `sudo losetup -d /dev/loop0` to unmount all the mountpoints for each partition ([source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/316407))
3. `sudo umount /path/to/intermediate/mountpoint` to unmount the virtualbox image ([source](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/05/mount-virtualbox-vdi-ubuntu/))